# SharePoint 2010 Content Deployment Jobs, Is it possible to exclude certain documents or libraries from the Deployment Job

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have authoring environment and production environment for my public facing site. Now the requirement that I have is there is one Private document library which should only be available in authoring environment and should never export to production. Is it possible to exclude certain documents or library from content deployment job?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. The Content Deployment Job is an all or nothing tool. There is no option to cherry-pick what content you want to be migrated.

The good news is that you can use the [Content Migration API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb249963.aspx) to customize your solution. I have used it extensively to create my own migration packages. It's complicated until you understand the technology involved. Basically it packages up just the content you want into a cab file and moves it to the destination server. The destination has a running job that picks up the package, reads the manifest and dumps it out onto it's targets.

Good luck (: